# Saving an OrderedDict to Julia Data Format

Tags: julia

I wish to use the [JLD](https://github.com/JuliaIO/JLD.jl/blob/master/doc/jld.md#reference) package to write an `OrderedDict` to file in such a way that I can subsequently read it back unchanged.

Here was my first effort:

```
using JLD, HDF5, DataStructures

function testjld()  
    res = OrderedDict("A" => 1, "B" => 2)
    filename = "c:/temp/test.jld"
    save(File(format"JLD", filename), "res", res)
    res2 = load(filename)["res"]
    #Check if round-tripping works
    res == res2
end
```

But the "round-tripping" doesn't work - the function returns `false`. It also raises a warning:

```
julia> testjld()
┌ Warning: type JLD.AssociativeWrapper{Core.String,Core.Int64,OrderedCollections.OrderedDict{Core.String,Core.Int64}} not present in workspace; reconstructing
└ @ JLD C:\Users\Philip\.julia\packages\JLD\1BoSz\src\jld_types.jl:703
false
```

After reading the docs, I thought that `JLD` does not support `OrderedDict` "out of the box", but does support `Dict` and I can use that fact to write my own [custom serialisation](https://github.com/JuliaIO/JLD.jl/blob/master/doc/jld.md#custom-serialization) for `OrderedDict`. Something like this:

```
struct OrderedDictSerializer
    d::Dict
end

JLD.writeas(data::OrderedDict) = OrderedDictSerializer(Dict("contents" => convert(Dict, data), 
                                                            "keyorder" => [k for (k, v) in data]))

function JLD.readas(serdata::OrderedDictSerializer)
    unordered = serdata.d["contents"]
    keyorder = serdata.d["keyorder"]
    OrderedDict((k, unordered[k]) for k in keyorder)
end
```

Hardly an exhaustive test, but this does seem to work:

```
julia> testjld()
true
```

Am I correct in thinking I need to write my own serializer for `OrderedDict`, and can my serializer be improved?

**EDIT**

The answer to to my question "Can my serializer be improved?" seems to be "It will have to be, though I don't yet understand how."

Consider the two following test functions:

```
function testjld2()
    res = OrderedDict("A" => [1.0,2.0],"B" => [3.0,4.0])
    #check if round-tripping of readas and writeas methods works:
    JLD.readas(JLD.writeas(res)) == res
end

function testjld3()
    res = OrderedDict("A" => [1.0,2.0],"B" => [3.0,4.0])
    filename = "c:/temp/test.jld"
    save(File(format"JLD", filename), "res", res)
    res2 = load(filename)["res"]
    #Check if round-tripping to jld file and back works
    res == res2
end
```

`testjld2` shows that my `writeas` and `readas` methods correctly round-trip for an `OrderedDict{String,Array{Float64,1}} with 2 entries`

```
julia> testjld2()
true
```

and yet `testjld3` doesn't work at all, but yields an error:

```
julia> testjld3()
HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.10.5) thread 0:
  #000: E:/mingwbuild/mingw-w64-hdf5/src/hdf5-1.10.5/src/H5Tfields.c line 60 in H5Tget_nmembers(): not a datatype
    major: Invalid arguments to routine
    minor: Inappropriate type
HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.10.5) thread 0:
  #000: E:/mingwbuild/mingw-w64-hdf5/src/hdf5-1.10.5/src/H5Tfields.c line 60 in H5Tget_nmembers(): not a datatype
    major: Invalid arguments to routine
    minor: Inappropriate type
ERROR: Error getting the number of members
Stacktrace:
 [1] error(::String) at .\error.jl:33
 [2] h5t_get_nmembers at C:\Users\Philip\.julia\packages\HDF5\rF1Fe\src\HDF5.jl:2279 [inlined]
 [3] _gen_h5convert!(::Any) at C:\Users\Philip\.julia\packages\JLD\1BoSz\src\jld_types.jl:638
 [4] #s27#9(::Any, ::Any, ::Any, ::Any, ::Any, ::Any) at C:\Users\Philip\.julia\packages\JLD\1BoSz\src\jld_types.jl:664
 [5] (::Core.GeneratedFunctionStub)(::Any, ::Vararg{Any,N} where N) at .\boot.jl:524
 [6] #write_compound#24(::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}, ::typeof(JLD.write_compound), ::JLD.JldGroup, ::String, ::JLD.AssociativeWrapper{String,Any,Dict{String,Any}}, ::JLD.JldWriteSession) at C:\Users\Philip\.julia\packages\JLD\1BoSz\src\JLD.jl:700
 [7] write_compound at C:\Users\Philip\.julia\packages\JLD\1BoSz\src\JLD.jl:694 [inlined]
 [8] #_write#23 at C:\Users\Philip\.julia\packages\JLD\1BoSz\src\JLD.jl:690 [inlined]
 [9] _write at C:\Users\Philip\.julia\packages\JLD\1BoSz\src\JLD.jl:690 [inlined]
 [10] write_ref(::JLD.JldFile, ::Dict{String,Any}, ::JLD.JldWriteSession) at C:\Users\Philip\.julia\packages\JLD\1BoSz\src\JLD.jl:658
 [11] macro expansion at C:\Users\Philip\.julia\packages\JLD\1BoSz\src\jld_types.jl:648 [inlined]
 [12] h5convert!(::Ptr{UInt8}, ::JLD.JldFile, ::OrderedDictSerializer, ::JLD.JldWriteSession) at C:\Users\Philip\.julia\packages\JLD\1BoSz\src\jld_types.jl:664
 [13] #write_compound#24(::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}, ::typeof(JLD.write_compound), ::JLD.JldFile, ::String, ::OrderedDictSerializer, ::JLD.JldWriteSession) at C:\Users\Philip\.julia\packages\JLD\1BoSz\src\JLD.jl:700
 [14] write_compound at C:\Users\Philip\.julia\packages\JLD\1BoSz\src\JLD.jl:694 [inlined]
 [15] #_write#23 at C:\Users\Philip\.julia\packages\JLD\1BoSz\src\JLD.jl:690 [inlined]
 [16] _write at C:\Users\Philip\.julia\packages\JLD\1BoSz\src\JLD.jl:690 [inlined]
 [17] #write#17(::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}, ::typeof(write), ::JLD.JldFile, ::String, ::OrderedDict{String,Array{Float64,1}}, ::JLD.JldWriteSession) at C:\Users\Philip\.julia\packages\JLD\1BoSz\src\JLD.jl:514
 [18] write at C:\Users\Philip\.julia\packages\JLD\1BoSz\src\JLD.jl:514 [inlined]
 [19] #35 at C:\Users\Philip\.julia\packages\JLD\1BoSz\src\JLD.jl:1223 [inlined]
 [20] #jldopen#14(::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Symbol,Bool,Tuple{Symbol,Symbol},NamedTuple{(:compatible, :compress),Tuple{Bool,Bool}}}, ::typeof(jldopen), ::getfield(JLD, Symbol("##35#36")){String,OrderedDict{String,Array{Float64,1}},Tuple{}},
::String, ::Vararg{String,N} where N) at C:\Users\Philip\.julia\packages\JLD\1BoSz\src\JLD.jl:246
 [21] testjld3() at .\none:0
 [22] top-level scope at REPL[48]:1
```

Comment: Do you need to serialize between different Julia versions or platforms? If this is not the case and you are not fixed on JLD, you could simply use https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Serialization/ This works without any flaw on your example.

Comment: Not totally fixed on JLD, though it would be nice to be able to tell non-Julia-using colleagues that the files are in an open format that they can inspect (with the right viewer app) rather than an "opaque format". My question was a slight over-simplification of the actual problem, as the elements of the OrderedDict include other types not supported by JLD so I have more serializers to write. So your suggestion might be the way I go!

Answer (score 1):

Use JLD2 instead:

```
using JLD2, DataStructures, FileIO
function testjld2()
    res = OrderedDict("A" => 1, "B" => 2)
    myfilename = "c:/temp/test.jld2"
    save(myfilename, "res", res)
    res2 = load(myfilename)["res"]
    #Check if round-tripping works
    res == res2
end
```

Testing:

```
julia> testjld2()
true
```

Personally, whenever I can I use BJSON:

```
using DataStructures, BSON, OrderedCollections
function testbson()
    res = OrderedDict("A" => 1, "B" => 2)
    myfilename = "c:/temp/test.bjson"
    BSON.bson(myfilename, Dict("res" => res))
    res2 = BSON.load(myfilename)["res"]
    #Check if round-tripping works
    res == res2
end
```

```
julia> testbson()
true
```